# When adding new Entity with existing referenced entity, EF 4.1 is tring to insert the existing referenced entity to the view

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I encountered a strange situation.

I have a root entity (table) with refereance to another entity (view)

```
public class RootEntity
{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public int SubEntityId {get; set;}

   public SubEntity SubEntity {get; set;}
}

public class SubEntity
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

When I set only the RootEntity.SubEntityId with existing SubEntityId All goes well.

But, when I set the Ref to as follow

```
RootEntity.SubEntity = attachedSubEntity
```

For whatever reason EF is trying to insert the attached SubEntity to the view and I get this

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column '****', table '****'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Comment: Show the code related to adding RootEntity and the way how you get attachedSubEntity. Btw. this is very common problem. When you asked the question it offered you plenty of related questions about the same problem. Did you at least read some of them?

Comment: Of course, I did extensive search on the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! `SubEntity` was fetched with `AsNoTracking` option.

I thought that using this option will solve the "Insert" problem but in fact he was the cause!

When I removed the `AsNoTracking` addition all goes well.

It's still weird because the problem occurred only when used UnitTesting (Nunit). But with WCF I not encountered the problem